# No application to launch in Eclipse Mobility Simulator

Tags: eclipse, java-me

I am running Eclipse Pulsar with Java ME SDK 3.0. When I try running my application, a screen appears with select one to launch, but it contains no options. Both the active Java ME configuration is set to use the ClamshellCldcPhone1 and I am using the Project Device in the run configuration. The executable is set to a Midlet. Any suggestions on what I may need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to open the Application Descriptor file, go to the MIDlets tab and add a new midlet with my midlet class.